# why fork- join is not supported in ISE Webpack?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ise

I am using the newest version of Xilinx ISE Webpack(v14.7). every time I try to use fork-join statement ( in Verilog ), I receive this error:

ERROR:Xst:850 : Unsupported Fork Statement.

Is this block type unsupported in Webpack or I am missing something?  Here is a very simple example:

[image]

Comment: @Tut my bad!  it is 14.7. edited in the question.

Comment: Is this in any particular language? I've never seen it in VHDL.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Verilog (also SystemVerilog)

Comment: @Aug You should include the language in your question.

Comment: aaah, I don't do Verilog. But wouldn't "fork/join" imply creating processes at runtime? If so, there's no way that will be synthesisable; you can't create or destroy gates on a running piece of hardware. And XST is a synthesis tool... Does the documentation happen to mention if this is a simulation-only construct? If so, Webpack probably does support it ... for simulation.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am not sure if it is a simulation-only construct but it does not give anything even for simulation .

Comment: @BrianDrummond I belive so ... From "Advanced Digital Design with the VERILOG HDL": "fork...join statements are helpful in modeling complex waveforms in testbenches and abstract (nonsynthesizable) models of behavior."

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think your comment is the answer to this question. Please leave it as answer that I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I don't do Verilog, it may be worth waiting for a Verilog expert to answer.

But meantime, wouldn't "fork/join" imply creating processes at runtime? If so, there's no way that will be synthesisable; you can't create or destroy gates on a running piece of hardware. And XST is a synthesis tool... (EDIT: technically gates *can* be destroyed but outside of fuse-based ROMs or PLDs it's not normal practice!)

Does the documentation happen to mention if this is a simulation-only construct? If so, Webpack probably does support it ... for simulation.

Incidentally I don't understand what "fork/join" is intended to accomplish here. In what I would guess to be the VHDL equivalent:

```
process(clk)
begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      a <= 1;
      b <= 1;
   end if;
end process;
```

the assignments to A and B take place simultaneously as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532) , so isn't fork/join redundant, or is Verilog even more different than I thought?

Comment: It looks redundant to me too. I don't know if this is legal syntax, but I would think the Verilog equivalent to the example using begin-end (and non-blocking operators <=) instead of fork-join would look like: always @(posedge clk) begin #2 a<=1; #1 b<=1; end